# converting toList() throws exception Object must implement IConvertible

Tags: mysql, linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-2, exception

I am getting this exception "`Object must implement IConvertible.`" while converting rules to tolist(). below is my code

```
var rules = from m in db.Rules select m;
 return rules.ToList().ToDataTable(); // exception occurs here
```

I am using MySQL 6.3.6 ..the same code is working fine with MSSQL.

I will be grateful if someone helps me in this

regards
Umair

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the source type is convertible to the destination type.
Probably the rules.ToList() don't match with you ToDataTable destination cast.

Can you verify what `var list = rules.ToList()` contains?

And... I suggest deal with List and IEnumerable against Datatable.